# Variables in Google Test Fixtures

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest, fixtures

Why TEST_F can access the member variable in a `class` without using any scopes? e.g.,

```
class ABC : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
     int a;
     int b;
     void SetUp()
     {      
         a = 1;
         b = 1;
     }

     virtual void TearDown()
     { 
     }
};

TEST_F(ABC, Test123)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(a == b);

}
```

why it can directly access `a` and `b`, instead of using `ABC::a` or `ABC::b`? Does the fixture create a variable for `class ABC`? if so, should it be `ASSERT_TRUE(abc.a == abc.b);` instead of `ASSERT_TRUE(a == b);`?

Comment: IIRC, `TEST_F` macro creates a subclass for `ABC` (that's why you are required to put everything in `protected`) and the body is put in a method that is later called by test runner. I can try to put up an answer tomorrow if you don't get anything by that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TEST_F is a macro which defines a new class publicly inheriting from the first argument (in this case, 'ABC'). So it has access to all public and protected members of the test fixture class.

You can inspect the source for this macro in the header file to get a better idea of what it's doing.

[TEST_F macro](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/8d51dc50eb7e7698427fed81b85edad0e032112e/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h#L2189), which if you follow the macro path leads you to...
[GTEST_TEST_ macro](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/8d51dc50eb7e7698427fed81b85edad0e032112e/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h#L1539)